# Using PagedCollectionView for four ListBoxes which support drag and drop = Index Errors when a filter is applied

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'm using Silverlight 3 and I have a dropdown menu which is used to filter four listboxes. These listboxes are individually wrapped within a ListBoxDragDropTarget (from the silverlight toolkit).

The idea being that a user can see all available items or filter their view (all four listboxes) by a specific category.

One listbox shows available items that can be assigned and then a user can drag from this list to one of the other three (which indicate what they want to do with the selected item. items can also be dragged across these three lists).

Everything works well until you use a filter and then drag an item onto a listbox which is empty (as a result of the filter).

The error I get is below and it is thrown when the item is being removed from the original list.

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

   at System.Windows.Data.PagedCollectionView.GetItemAt(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Data.PagedCollectionView.get_IsCurrentInSync()
   at System.Windows.Data.PagedCollectionView.AdjustCurrencyForRemove(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Data.PagedCollectionView.ProcessRemoveEvent(Object removedItem,     Boolean isReplace)
   at System.Windows.Data.PagedCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChanged                          (NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.PagedCollectionView.b__0(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.RemoveItem(Int32 index)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
```

Has anyone come across a similar error. Is PagedCollectionView (which is passed an observable collection) the wrong way of going about this?

Any insight from someone who's come across this would be appreciated.

Comment: After looking at this for a while and trying a few things I decided against using PagedCollectionView. It has some nice features but it felt as if it wasn't the best choice for what I wanted to do (for general filtering, sorting it seems great). Ended up having a source and view list for each listbox where the source was updated to reflect changes (add/remove) to the view list and the view list was filtered when the dropdown was changed.

Comment: I get the same, but without drag-and-drop. It happens when you remove something from the source list (the one used by the PagedCollectionView), but it does not happen every time. My workaround is to catch and ignore the exception, because everything still works.